How do I increment a date value in Google sheets until the date value is in the future?
I am trying to calculate the next future invoicing date given an initial renewal date and a increment time (given in months) without using Google scripts.
Example - This should reflect the updated current date,
not a static or hardcoded date. 

Assuming current date is 8/5/2024

StartDate | Increment (months) | Result
7/14/2024   1                    8/14/2024
7/2/2024    1                    9/2/2024
7/14/2016   12                   7/14/2025
7/14/2022   6                    2/14/2025


Assuming current date is 8/14/2024

StartDate | Increment (months) | Result
7/14/2024   1                    8/14/2024
7/2/2024    1                    9/2/2024
7/14/2016   12                   7/14/2025
7/14/2022   6                    2/14/2025

I have had so much trouble finding information on this question that I figured a SO post would be appreciated by anybody with the issue.

The question tags both Excel AND Google Sheets. Would you please select one or the other, but not both. The question also tags VBA and Apps Script, but the question appears to look for an answer that does NOT use code. Would you please clarify, and remove one or both tags as the case may be.

Try =DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+B1,DAY(A1)).

Is row2(of your test data) expected output supposed to be 2-Aug-24 or 2-Sep-24 to meet the future date requirement? same query for 4th row as well....

Please provide minimal reproducible example. On your question you are in need of today's date but there is not clarification how it was affecting your target result. Along with your Reproducible sample. Can you edit your post to give clarification with your expected result and current dataset. Thank you.

Thank you for editing your question. I want to understand this Assuming current date is 8/14/2024what effects does it have with your table with results? With your example it has a different current date but with no changes on the table.


You may try:
=let(date_,A2, inc_,B2,
     loop_,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(Λ>=today(),Λ,Σ(Σ,edate(Λ,inc_)))),
     loop_(loop_,date_))



This worked exactly how I needed it to, just applied it to my dataset and verified the outputs. Thank you greatly for your help! You have already done so much, but if you could provide any resources or explanation of this that would be greatly appreciated! I am familiar with lambda functions but not the use of the summation symbol, nor the use of the "Λ" in this function.
